# Is there a way to extend a table to be a valid time state table

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I'm trying to extend a table to allow for valid time state on the table. I can create the index with valid time state, and add custom fields for from and to dates. However, I cannot set the property on the parent table node for the valid time state field property.

Is extending an out of the box table to be valid time state enabled supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *ValidTimeStateFieldType* property cannot be extended.

You can add ValidFrom and ValidTo date fields manually, but you will have to implement the date limeting logic yourself, which can be tricky.